# Problem with jquery ajax in Opera and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, opera

I have a page where I need to add a drag and drop functionality to certain elements. When the drop event occurs, it makes an ajax call to a php function and then refreshes the contents of a div. I'm using jQuery with jQueryUI for the drag and drop, and CakePHP as a PHP framework (not sure if this is relevant).

Everything is working just fine in Firefox, Safari and even IE, but in Opera or Chrome the contents of the div isn't refreshed (although the action from the PHP function is executed).

So, here is the code:

```
jQuery('#lists div').
    filter(function() {return this.id.match(/item[\d]+_[\d]+/);}).
    each(function() { jQuery(this).draggable( {axis: 'y'}); });

jQuery('#lists div').
    filter(function() {
        return this.id.match(/list[\d]+/);}).
               each(function() { 
                   jQuery(this).droppable({
                      drop: function(event, ui) {
                            dropID = jQuery(event.target).attr('id');
                            dragID = jQuery(ui.draggable).attr('id');

                            itemID = dragID.substr(dragID.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
                            oldListID = dragID.substr(4).replace(/_[\d]+/g, '');
                            newListID = drop.substr(4);

                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url:  "/lists/itemToList/"+itemID+"/"+oldListID+
                                      "/"+newListID,
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (data) {
                                     jQuery('#lists').html(data);}
                            });
                         }
                 });
    });
```

Basically, the success function isn't executed, but if I try to see the errorThrown (on the error event) it is "undefined"

Comment: Could you post the URL to this page, or a demo? There isn't really enough here to tell why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since I've posted the question, but here is what I found to be the solution, in case somebody else needs it: the problem was not the in javascript but with CakePHP: the html that was added on success contained an ajax form (rendered using $ajax->form()). $ajax->form() needed the $data variable from the controller to be an array, but for some reason it wasn't, and this broke the rendering of the form, and Opera and Chrome didn't like this. So the solution was to simply add

```
$this->data = array();
```

to the itemToList() function in my controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url:  "/lists/itemToList/"+itemID+"/"+oldListID+
      "/"+newListID,
   type: "POST",
   success: function (data) {
      jQuery('#lists').html(data);
   }
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
      alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
   }
});
```

It will show you what http response are you getting for your request. I had the same problem some time ago. My script worked great in Firefox and Chrome, but it didn't do anything in Opera and IE. I checked it and the problem was, that the php backend was returning 404 (I still don't know how did it work under Chrome and FF).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply. It is not a 404 error, I tried what you said and the status is 0 and the responseText is empty in Opera. In Chrome the status is 500 and the responseText is also empty. I have no idea what could be causing this.
The really strange part: this code basically moves items from one list to another. There are two different ways to do this: drag and drop, or choose the destination list from a select list. The second option works just fine, although it calls the same action, updates the same div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the code that would cause a cross browser issue.  My feeling is that it's a problem doesn't lie in the code at all, but in the rendering of the div and/or its contents in Chrome and Opera (i.e. a CSS problem or something along those lines where the `innerHTML` of the div is updated, but because of styling or positioning you don't get the visual result you were looking for).

Have you checked using Dragonfly or some other developer tool to verify that the contents of the target element are in fact unchanged after a successful request?  Along those lines have you tried stepping through the code execution in the problem browsers?  You could also try adding a `error` handler to the `JQuery.ajax` options to see if there is some problem with the request itself, although I don't believe that is where the problem lies.

EDIT: I didn't see that last bit below the code block.  So you have verified that the success handler isn't being executed.  You said that you did try and implement an error handler for the request and got some undefined result, but I don't see it in the code.  Could you post the code for the error handler and describe what in the error is undefined?

Comment: I've tried using Dragonfly, and the contents of the div remains the same. When I try to see the status of the request, in Opera it is 0, in Chrome it is 500.

Answer (score 0):

I think he means, that alert(errorThrown) is showing 'undefined'.